# Функции как методы в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Можно ли использовать функцию как метод в js? Например есть функция `stop`.

```
function stop() {
    console.log('stop');
}
stop();
```

То есть можно вызвать функцию через точку .stop()? Если да, то покажите пожалуйста на примере. Только учу js.

Comment: @meine, честно нет еще. хочу полностью функции понять.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var t = {
 stop: function(){
    console.log('stop');
 }
}

t.stop();
```

Comment: Интересно, кто минусует верный ответ....

Comment: @Air, например я, за отсутствие ответа и только за непонятный блок кода, который непонятно что делает.

Comment: @Grundy,  Странно...

Answer (score 0):

Использовать `object.method()` можно только в том случае, если метод определён в объекте как его свойство. Поэтому обычную функцию так использовать нельзя, она не будет найдена в объекте перед вызовом. Разве что вы сначала определите функцию, а потом присвоите её объекту:

```js
function stop() {
    console.log('stop');
}
const obj = { stop: stop };
obj.stop();
```

Но можно повторить смысл такого вызова. Так как смысл его в том, чтобы метод мог использовать объект как значение `this` внутри себя, можно явно вызвать функцию, указав на объект как на `this`:

```js
stop.call(object);
```

или:

```js
stop.bind(object)();
```

См. [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) и [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).